# Find word count using wc and assign to a variable

Tags: unix

i want the word count wc -w value be assigned to a variable

i've tried something like this, but i'm getting error, what is wrong?

```
winget="this is the first line"

wdCount=$winget | wc -w

echo $wdCount
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to `$(...)` to assign the result:

```
wdCount=$(echo $winget | wc -w)
```

Or you could also avoid `echo` by using *here-document*:

```
wdCount=$(wc -w <<<$winget)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass word count without the filename using the following:

```
num_of_lines=$(< "$file" wc -w)
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126999/320461

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to store the word count in variable:

`word_count=$(wc -w filename.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`

Comment: There would be no point in piping wc to awk when awk could do the counting for you - awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { cnt++ } } END { print cnt }'